# Dynamic pointer to Image object at WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have list of dynamically created images and buttons near them at WP app.
Each button shows CameraCaptureTask, on task completion I want to bind captured image to image, that lies near given button.
I created kind of global pointer

```
Image currentImage;
```

On button Tap before task show I assign Image near it to that pointer

```
currentImage = createdImage;
```

On task complete I'm trying to assign Image to that pointer

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
currentImage.Source = bmp;
```

But it doesn't work.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that after photocapture page have been reloaded.